Looker - Expected expression "filter_name" in "condition" to be a field name
I am trying to create a dynamic-derived table in Looker using Templated Filters / Liquid parameters. But I am getting the below error.
Error: Expected expression "approval_status_param" in "condition" to be a field name.
LookML Code:
view: derived_table {
  
  parameter: approval_status_param {
    label: "Approval Status Parameter"
    type: string
    
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Approved"
      value: "APPROVED"
    }
    allowed_value: {
      label: "Rejected"
      value: "REJECTED"
    }
  }
  
  derived_table: {
    sql: select * from `gcp_project_id.dataset_name.table_name` as rv
    where
    {% condition approval_status_param %} 
      rv.approval_status 
    {% endcondition %}
    ;;    
  }
  

  dimension: approval_status {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.approval_status ;;
  }
}

I am referring to the Looker documentation for this which you can find here. But still getting the error as mentioned above.

I got a similar warning while working on a project recently.
I resolved it by adding the filter also as a dimension in that view.
Not exactly sure what is going on here, but it worked. Have to check if that introduces any unforeseen bugs in the results.
